# Why do runners wear helmets?

Tags: cricket, equipment

Why do they have to wear knee pads for that matter?

I watched so many matches and I always wondered why the bye runners ever have to wear a helmet?

Comment: Please note that the correct term, as used in the Laws, is [_runner_](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/) rather than "bye-runner". Runners have no particular connection with the concept of [_byes_](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-26-bye-and-leg-bye/).

Answer (score 5):

As per the cricketing rules,

> The player acting as a runner for a batsman shall be a member of the
>   batting side and shall, if possible, have already batted in that
>   innings. The runner shall wear external protective equipment
>   equivalent to that worn by the batsman for whom he runs and shall
>   carry a bat.

Helmets,pads and other things are external protective equipment which is worn by the batsman needs to be worn by the runner too.

**Note:** Currently bye-runners rule is not available. The rule is removed since it was used in a wrong way.

**[Reference:](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/)**

Comment: what was the wrong way?

Comment: @neena Taking advantages from that rule. Like he is fine but still asking for bye-runner to not to waste the energy.

Comment: is it true that runners provision is completely obsolete?

Comment: yup. [reference](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/520924.html)

Comment: @neena It is not completely obsolete. Runners are still part of the Laws, so they may be used in any match unless otherwise stated. To prevent runners, the provision has to be explicitly removed, as has been the case in international cricket since 2009. Therefore you may see runners in village cricket, for instance, but not in Test cricket (as of 2015).

Answer (score 2):

The role of a runner is a replacement for the injured batsman. In the interest of fairness to the fielding side, the runner must wear all the external protective equipment worn by the batsman he is running for, and must carry a bat.

This is obsolete now. Runners have been abolished from all forms of international cricket.